# Sharepoint - How to update list from an Excel file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list in Sharepoint, and I update it every week with a Excel file...

But every time I do it, I have to delete all items and import my Excel file..

Is there an easier way to do this?

I was thinking in Access, but I dont know if it is possible

Comment: Hi @Thiago, I think my answer on the SharePoint SE might be useful to you. It is very thorough and tested.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Excel or Access:

Excel: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-help/synchronize-a-list-with-a-spreadsheet-program-HA102815832.aspx

Access: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-from-or-link-data-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA102749600.aspx

Comment: No, you need only Microsoft Office and credentials to access SharePoint.

Comment: so i guess i dont have credentials to access Sharepoint... cause in Excel my button Export is disabled =(

Comment: so i dont know why my button is disabled... could it be a permission problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Datasheet view. Create a view containing all required fields. Open that view using Datasheet view action in ribbon. You can use Copy and Paste operations to import data from Excel to sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

Export key is enabled when your data is in tabular format