# Updating a sharepoint list from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I know this is a little backwards, but unfortunately this is what I have to do based on what I have to work with.  Essentially we are getting data from one place, putting it into Excel and then running some pivot tables and then copying and pasting the results to Sharepoint. There is no way of getting the data into SharePoint from its initial source.

So here are the steps I have to do on a daily basis:

1. Go into 3 lists on sharepoint and delete the current data in there
2. Copy the data from each excel table and then paste it into the associated SharePoint list
3. Go into the Titles, etc part of SharePoint and update the file name to append the current date to it(ie change it from Data05032017 to Data 05042017)

I would like a way of automating this on a daily basis from Excel by simply pressing a button via VBA or if there is a way I can accomplish this wia linking somehow that would work too(not sure if its possible, I know you can link from SharePoint to Excel but unsure if you can go in the reverse direction).

So I first would like to know if this is possible and then if it is, how  I go about doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharepoint - How to update list from a Excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933679/sharepoint-how-to-update-list-from-a-excel-file)

Comment: Is there a way to do it via VBA?  That would be the preferred method...